# Regex.Replace function and reading a text file

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, datetime-parsing

```
StreamReader ReadFile;
            ReadFile = File.OpenText("..\\..\\WeatherForecasts.txt");
            string line = ReadFile.ReadLine();
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(line) == false)
            {
                txtCity.Text = Regex.Replace(ReadFile.ReadLine(), "City: ", String.Empty);
                dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Parse(Regex.Replace(ReadFile.ReadLine(), "Date: ", String.Empty));
                MinT.Value = decimal.Parse(Regex.Replace(ReadFile.ReadLine(), "Minimum temperature: ", String.Empty));
                MaxT.Value = decimal.Parse(Regex.Replace(ReadFile.ReadLine(), "Maximum temperature: ", String.Empty));
                Prec.Value = decimal.Parse(Regex.Replace(ReadFile.ReadLine(), "Precipitation: ", String.Empty));
                Humidity.Value = decimal.Parse(Regex.Replace(ReadFile.ReadLine(), "Humidity: ", String.Empty));
                WindSpeed.Value = decimal.Parse(Regex.Replace(ReadFile.ReadLine(), "Wind Speed: ", String.Empty));
            }


            ReadFile.Close();
```

actually this is working but if any data is stored in WeatherForecasts.txt

I get this error message:

```
System.FormatException: 'The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.'
```

so I changed like

```
                    Regex.Replace(ReadFile.ReadLine(), "City: ", String.Empty);
                    Regex.Replace(ReadFile.ReadLine(), "Date: ", String.Empty);
                    Regex.Replace(ReadFile.ReadLine(), "Minimum temperature: ", String.Empty);
                    Regex.Replace(ReadFile.ReadLine(), "Maximum temperature: ", String.Empty);
                    Regex.Replace(ReadFile.ReadLine(), "Precipitation: ", String.Empty);
                    Regex.Replace(ReadFile.ReadLine(), "Humidity: ", String.Empty);
                    Regex.Replace(ReadFile.ReadLine(), "Wind Speed: ", String.Empty);
```

and I got a different error

```
System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: input'
```

if i don't store data, it works perfectly.

and this is what data is stored in WeatherForecasts.txt now

```
City: dddd
Date: 5/27/2020 12:00:00 AM
Minimum temperature: 1
Maximum temperature: 1
Precipitation: -1
Humidity: -2
Wind Speed: 1
```

sorry, I don't know what you need, so if you need any other information, please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception you are getting is related to the Date parsing. By default, `Date.Parse` uses the computer local settings to parse the date, but it probably does not match the date you are providing (US regional format).
Use the [Date.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netcore-3.1) with the following format:

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.ParseExact(Regex.Replace(ReadFile.ReadLine(), "Date: ", String.Empty),"M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: but it has to be read from the txt file. That is why i used 'ReadFile.ReadLine();'

Comment: i am really sorry but i am still getting this error message:

Comment: System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

Comment: Can you post the value of the text you are getting after Regex.Replace?

Comment: if i don't store data, i don't get any value.

Comment: Why store data? Try to see what value you are getting on this call Regex.Replace(ReadFile.ReadLine(), "Date: ", String.Empty).

Comment: i mean how can i check the value if i get the error message? sorry i am newbie

Comment: The error is coming from Date.Parse function.Try to break down the function calls: var s = ReadFile.ReadLine() ; var afterReg = Regex.Replace(s, "Date: ", String.Empty); See the value of s and afterReg.

Comment: oh my goodness, now i am getting new error for others. Do i need to break down the rest of them as well like that? for example, var MinT = Regex.Replace(s, "Minimum Temperature: ", String.Empty)